# ggplot2 - geom_density(): how to change legend title and order

Tags: r, ggplot2

i created a density diagram for a set of data, divided by the different weekdays.

```
ggplot(template, aes(x=test, color=as.factor(Weekday))) + geom_density()
```

Now i would like to change the order in the legend of the diagram. Right now it is ordered alphabetically (Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday), would like to have to ordered Mon, Tues, Wed...
A second thing i would like to do is change the title of the legend which is right now "as.factor(Weekday)".

I appreciate any suggestions and help,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: shame on me! i figured out how to deal with the title of the legend "+ theme(legend.title=element_blank())". But sill no idea how to reorder the Weekdays

Answer (score 2):

Give command:

```
weekday = factor(weekday, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

For programming related questions, you should post at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you! sry for the post here, i just didn't think about the programming relation of my question but you are right!